# How to set reference to the variable in jetty configuration file

Tags: maven-jetty-plugin

I'm trying to execute run-forked via maven Port number is stored as environment variable "jetty-start-port"

How to set reference to the variable in jetty configuration file to this tag 
**`<Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="8081"/></Set>`**?

Jetty.xml looks like:

```
<Configure id="FileServer" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

  <Call name="addConnector">
  <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
        <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
        <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="8081"/></Set>
        <Set name="maxIdleTime">300000</Set>
        <Set name="Acceptors">4</Set>
        <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
        <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>
    <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">20000</Set>
    <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
      </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
</Configure>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like need to change  `<Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="8081"/></Set>` to `<Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty-start-port"/></Set>`